# .NET Core app version conflict

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to get a basic .NET Core app up and running. I created an empty *Core Web application* in Visual Studio 2015. 
I did not make any changes before trying to build and run. I am getting an error on the package restore.  I have one project in the solution. How should I fix this?

> error: Version conflict detected for System.Net.Http.
>
> error:  Test (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 1.0.0) -> System.Net.Requests (>= 4.0.11) -> System.Net.Http (>= 4.1.0)
>
> error:  Test (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 1.0.0) -> NETStandard.Library (>= 1.6.0) -> System.Net.Http (>= 4.1.0).
>
> error: Project System.Net.Http is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Project System.Net.Http supports: net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
>
> error: One or more projects are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

project.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your `project.json`

Comment: Please try changing `Microsoft.NETCore.App` dependency (3 line in project.json) like that: `"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    }`

Comment: I updated this and has the same error

Comment: Just to be sure. my nuget is pointing to https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message suggests that NuGet has found a **project** named System.Net.Http and is using that instead of the **package** System.Net.Http.

> error: ***Project*** System.Net.Http is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0).

If it were an issue with packages, the restore message would say **Package** instead of **Project**.

> I have one project in the solution.

Check that you don't have a project named System.Net.Http next to your "Test" project, or in any folders configured via the global.json file. The project.json project system will still find the project even if it is not included in your Visual Studio .sln file.

Comment: My issue might be just a coincidence. Since I was trying to get a empty app up and running, I did not care about the where I was saving the sln file. I was fine as soon as I checked, create a separate folder for solution.  After looking at you response, I just checked the folder where I was saving this sln file and I have all my test projects/slns there with some global json files too

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're mixing .NET Core version 1.0 and 1.1. Also, your dependency specification on `Microsoft.NETCore.App` is incorrect. Try updating it to:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "type": "platform"
}
```

If you wish to use .NET Core and ASP.NET Core 1.1 (the latest 'Current' version), update your dependencies accordingly:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "version": "1.1.0",
        "type": "platform"
    }
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  // etc..
}
```

Comment: I updated the specification on Microsoft.NETCore.App to:"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "type": "platform"
}. Still the same error